# Creating a relational structure

Tags: sql-server, database-design, entity

Scenario:

I have some 
MAIN_TABLE1 
MAIN_TABLE2 
these main tables are in relational schema.

Now, I need to move the data from this relational schema to some other flat tables:

flat_Parent_Table 
        flat_Child_Table1
        flat_Child_Table2
              flat_GrandChild1
              flat_GrandChild2

Now one record from MAIN_TABLE1 goes to multiple flat tables. Now what should be the logic here to move the data in these flat tables and create a relational schema on these flat table.

Comment: An example would help. Please post your schema and desired "flattened" result. Then we may actually offer a solution, this is way too vague.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Extract, Transform, Load ([ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)) problem.  If you're using SQL Server 2005 or above, you can use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx).  If not, you can use [DTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx).  The precise logic for how you de-normalize your data depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  There are many good [books on that subject](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247).  Also, check out the [Kimball Group](http://www.ralphkimball.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The logic is up to you, but the process would be to build a script (perhaps Perl) to connect to the DB, read the records out of the main tables, and apply the insert stmts to push the data into the child tables.